# Matrix Ordinary differential Equation in Python

Tags: python, matrix, ode

I need to solve an ODE in the following form:

[image]

where, I want to find *A(t)* and *C(t)* is a known *8x8* matrix. The problem is that I'm only able to write this matrix as a list of matrices, for each time I have a matrix written in a list (The dimension of it is `[8,8,1000]`, *1000* because I've evaluated it in the interval [0,1] with dt = .001). It is written in that way because I don't know its analytical explicit expression.

I've found this library that solves matrix ODE:

[odeintw](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw)

But when I try to use it I get:

```
from odeintw import odeintw
def asys(a, t, c):
    return c.dot(a) -a.dot(c)
c = Mymatrix #[8,8,1000]
a0 = rho0
t = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
sol = odeintw(asys, a0, t)
```

This error:

```
ValueError: shapes (8,8,1000) and (8,8) not aligned: 1000 (dim 2) != 8 (dim 0)
```

but I have no idea on how to use it to solve my problem or if its possible. Can some one help me please?

Comment: It's not the exact same, but Example 2 in the Readme of the link you provided seems very close to the equation you are working with.

Comment: I've tried but I got an ERROR

Comment: What are your import statements for the code you provided?

Comment: I used the library as the github proposed

Comment: Did you do `import odeintw` or `from odeintw import odeintw`. The former is the source of the exception you are getting, the latter is the proper format to import the `odeintw` function from the package.

Comment: I was Importing it wrong, but now I've got other error

Answer (score 1):

The error `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` is often the result of a faulty import statement.

### Case 1 - Importing 'odeintw' package

```
import numpy as np
import odeintw

def asys(a, t, c):
    return c.dot(a) - a.dot(c)

a0 = 9
t = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
sol = odeintw(asys, a0, t)
```

**Result**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    sol = odeintw(asys, a0, t)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

### Case 2 - Importing `odeintw` function from the package

```
import numpy as np
from odeintw import odeintw

def asys(a, t, c):
    return c.dot(a) - a.dot(c)

c = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
a0 = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])
t = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
sol = odeintw(asys, a0, t)
```

**Result**

```
[[[   5.            6.        ]
  [   7.            8.        ]]

 [[   4.99602602    5.98801394]
  [   7.01201813    8.00397398]]

 [[   4.99211203    5.97607958]
  [   7.02404867    8.00788797]]

 ...

 [[ 176.46661225  -74.83312649]
  [ 385.4496081  -163.46661225]]

 [[ 177.46587768  -75.29026227]
  [ 387.63420993 -164.46587768]]

 [[ 178.47090603  -75.75003391]
  [ 389.83140992 -165.47090603]]]
```

### Analysis

The main difference between the Cases is that in Case 1, you are importing a full module and then attempting to call it and assign it's return value to `sol`. In Case 2, you are importing the function `odeintw` from the module, and then calling it and assigning it's value to `sol`.

Comment: The problem is that my `C` is a time dependent array, written as a list of matrices. It has dimension [8,8,1000], 1000 matrices, one for each time. If I tried this way I get this error: `ValueError: shapes (8,8,1000) and (8,8) not aligned: 1000 (dim 2) != 8 (dim 0)`

Comment: Then you would call the function 1000 times, one for each matrix, I would presume? Wrapping it in a for-loop should work. I'm not sure how that will affect your overall calculation, but that's a solution to use the above sample.

Comment: Doing it 1000 times solves a different problem. The output of ONE loop cycle in this case will be `[8,8,1000]`, as if the problem was an time independent `C`. If I loop I will get 1000 time the solution for the constant case.